# Ionic3 JSON http.get data issue

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework

Apologies if this is near a duplicate question, however all other question are either un answered or not quite as close to this issue.

I'm in Ionic 3 and I am using this code to get JSON from a feed:

```
getMenu(){

    let path = 'URL';
    let encodedPath = encodeURI(path);

    this.http.get(encodedPath)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      let responseData = data;
      if(responseData.status=='success'){
        var JSONObject = responseData.data;
        this.menuItems = JSONObject;
        console.log(JSONObject);
      }
    },
    err => {
        console.log('error ' + err);
    });
}
```

I call that function in both ionViewDidLoad and the constructor. And then in my page I'm trying to access the data in that feed on the page with:

```
{{ menuItems.length }} etc etc
```

I think i'm aware of the fact that the data will probably come in after the page has loaded as the error i'm getting is

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The console does show me the correct data that is pulled in, good. But as I have read, this will happen asynchronously. All the tutorials I have read say it just works, well it certainly doesn't!! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try using {{ menuItems?.length }} - if it works then I'll tell you why

Comment: Ahhh, how VERY annoying!!! I had been trying with the question mark but putting it in the wrong place menuItems.length?

Am I right in thinking that that sets the variable to be ready to look for a change in the HTML?

Apologies in the question duplication, do I just remove the question?